# Populate Joomla userid Progammtically

Tags: joomla2.5, session-cookies, userid

Using Cometchat with cross domain settings on a Joomla 2.5 site.

Cometchat bar shows correctly and is grabbing the correct session information but not populating the userid in the URL.  So when a user logs into the main site they are not logged into Cometchat.

Code placed in head.php of joomla library as provided by Cometchat is:

`$buffer . = '<script>
var userid = "USERID"; // Must be populated programmatically
document.cookie = "cc_data="+userid;
</script>'`

Rather than the correct userid the url ends with "basedata=USERID" as noted in the above script.  If the link shown in errors section is manually changed to add the correct userid logs cometchat shows the user as logged in.

Any code I use to try to supply the userid dymnaically throws an error of either Unknown identifier or Illegal token.

I have been over the net all over trying to find this one bit of info to no avail.  HELP!

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getUser

```
// this gets the user object
$user =& JFactory::getUser();

// if user is not a guest print the following user info
if (!$user->guest) {
  echo 'You are logged in as:<br />';
  echo 'User name: ' . $user->username . '<br />';
  echo 'Real name: ' . $user->name . '<br />';
  echo 'User ID  : ' . $user->id . '<br />';  // if you need id this is it
}
```

Comment: What I can't get it to do is print the id data into the "USERID" section of the orginal code.  Subsituting the code for "USERID" after deleting out the first 3 echos and the added text just prints the actual code "echo $user->id" instead of "USERID".